# Jquery UI animate no applying effect to floated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I created a fiddle to explain the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/E5XvT/2/

I'm using the Jquery UI's animate function to fade in background color for an element with the following code:

HTML:

```
<div id="element">   
<h1>test</h1>
<div id="child">not animated</div>
<div id="child">not animated</div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #element {
 width:300px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 } 
 #child {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 100px;
 float: left;
 }
```

Jquery:

```
$('#element').animate({backgroundColor: '#FFFF99'}, 'slow');
```

The problem is that this function is not applying the effect to the floated child elements.
If I remove the floating, it works

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the floats in the parent element, you'd usually have a clearfix class, here is Nicolas Gallagher microclearfix...

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

then simply write:

```
<div id="element" class="cf">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add overflow: hidden; to the parent to respect the height of the children:

```
#element{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

or

Add an empty element with clear:both as the latest element:

```
<div id="element">   
 <h1>test</h1>
 <div id="child">not animated</div>
 <div id="child">not animated</div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting the `overflow` property is enough.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) for the floated descendant (as floated elements are taken out of the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comp-normal-flow)) - add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent, `#element`

http://jsfiddle.net/E5XvT/7/